# How can I make sharp steps from a bump map?

Tags: height-map, bump

I want to load the following image and create a shape that looks like a cube stacking up in the back.
[image: bump map image]

[image: shading editor]

In reality, it would be smooth as shown in the figure.
[image: result]
The division format of the Bump map and the subdivision format of the object match.

Is it possible to load the Bump map information for each face?

Comment: It's not possible like that. Because the displacement information is moving the vertices and even if they would move the faces, as long as the faces share the edges/vertices with their neighbours, how should the stacking effect be achieved? An edge between two faces where one gets a value of e.g. 0.5 and the other 0.6, how should the edge be at a height of 0.5 and 0.6 at the same time? To achieve this the faces need to be separate from each other or be extruded. But this would be a completely different approach and unfortunately I have no time atm.